# How does a programmer deal with problems arising out of runtime additions of this kind to an array?

Tags: php

The array problem I asked can be seen in this code.

```
$sample=array('2'=>"A", "abc"=>"B", 2=>"C");
$sample_keys=array_keys($sample);
foreach ($sample_keys as $keys)
{
   echo $keys, $sample[$keys],"\n";
}

The output is
2C
abcB
```

**$sample[0] gives an error, so does $sample[1]**

How does a programmer deal with problems arising out of runtime additions of this kind to an array?
I am newbie in php

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you've defined the keys and values of your array. So to access the first element you'd actually use `$sample['2']`, second would be `$sample['abc'], third would be `$sample[2]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be `$sample[0]` when you do not ever define that key in the very first line of code in your snippet?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: While it's a roundabout way, it does work.  Note the iteration is over `$sample_keys`. Each value of `$sample_keys` is a key in `$sample`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): **"Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key '8' will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand '08' will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer."**

Therefore, in your code:

```
$sample_keys=array_keys($sample);
```

The variable `$sample_keys` only contains the values `2` and `abc`.

As far as you comment "`$sample[0]` gives an error, so does `$sample[1]`," of course they do. Your array doesn't contain the keys `0` and `1`. It contains `2` and `abc`.

The programmer can control this type of thing at runtime by planning ahead for the possible values that can be added to an array. If necessary, he can use functions such as `array_key_exists` to find out if a given key is in an array and make adjustments as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to loop through an array is:

```
$sample=array('2'=>"A", "abc"=>"B", 2=>"C");
foreach ($sample as $k => $v)
{
   echo "key=$k,value=$v,"\n";
}
```

So there is no runtime issue for PHP, like say for C++. foreach knows when the array finishes.